# Is there a way to import VBA modules on Workbook open?

Tags: excel, vba, import, module

I am trying to get it so that when a workbook opens, it checks a folder online  and then if the VBA file has been updated, it overwrites the old one in the Workbook. In this folder would be 4 .bas files. Is there a way do do this?

Comment: I know a way to do it manually (doesn't check for the time of the files) but will delete all your modules and import them back from the folder, if it helps you... You can tweak it to avoid deleting some modules.

Comment: @Damian Hiya, Yes that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code a long ago probably here or in some other web. As stated in the previous answer you need to activate that option for this to work.

You need two modules

Import module:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ImportModules()
    Dim wkbTarget As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim szTargetWorkbook As String
    Dim szImportPath As String
    Dim szFileName As String
    Dim cmpComponents As VBIDE.VBComponents
'
'    If ActiveWorkbook.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
'        MsgBox "Select another destination workbook" & _
'        "Not possible to import in this workbook "
'        Exit Sub
'    End If

    'Get the path to the folder with modules
    If FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = "Error" Then
        MsgBox "Import Folder not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ''' NOTE: This workbook must be open in Excel.
    szTargetWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set wkbTarget = Application.Workbooks(szTargetWorkbook)

    If wkbTarget.VBProject.Protection = 1 Then
    MsgBox "The VBA in this workbook is protected," & _
        "not possible to Import the code"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    ''' NOTE: Path where the code modules are located.
    szImportPath = FolderWithVBAProjectFiles & "\"

    Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    If objFSO.GetFolder(szImportPath).Files.Count = 0 Then
       MsgBox "There are no files to import"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    'Delete all modules/Userforms from the ActiveWorkbook
    Call DeleteVBAModulesAndUserForms

    Set cmpComponents = wkbTarget.VBProject.VBComponents

    ''' Import all the code modules in the specified path
    ''' to the ActiveWorkbook.
    For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(szImportPath).Files
        If objFile.Name Like "*Modulos*" Then GoTo Siguiente 'here to skip modules which name contain "Modulos"
        If (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "cls") Or _
            (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "frm") Or _
            (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "bas") Then
            cmpComponents.Import objFile.Path
        End If
Siguiente:
    Next objFile

    MsgBox "Módulos actualizados"
End Sub
```

Export module:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ExportModules()
    Dim bExport As Boolean
    Dim wkbSource As Excel.Workbook
    Dim szSourceWorkbook As String
    Dim szExportPath As String
    Dim szFileName As String
    Dim cmpComponent As VBIDE.VBComponent

    ''' The code modules will be exported in a folder named.
    ''' VBAProjectFiles in the Documents folder.
    ''' The code below create this folder if it not exist
    ''' or delete all files in the folder if it exist.
    If FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = "Error" Then
        MsgBox "Export Folder not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        Kill FolderWithVBAProjectFiles & "\*.*"
    On Error GoTo 0

    ''' NOTE: This workbook must be open in Excel.
    szSourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set wkbSource = Application.Workbooks(szSourceWorkbook)

    If wkbSource.VBProject.Protection = 1 Then
    MsgBox "The VBA in this workbook is protected," & _
        "not possible to export the code"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    szExportPath = FolderWithVBAProjectFiles & "\"

    For Each cmpComponent In wkbSource.VBProject.VBComponents

        bExport = True
        szFileName = cmpComponent.Name

        ''' Concatenate the correct filename for export.
        Select Case cmpComponent.Type
            Case vbext_ct_ClassModule
                szFileName = szFileName & ".cls"
            Case vbext_ct_MSForm
                szFileName = szFileName & ".frm"
            Case vbext_ct_StdModule
                szFileName = szFileName & ".bas"
            Case vbext_ct_Document
                ''' This is a worksheet or workbook object.
                ''' Don't try to export.
                bExport = False
        End Select
        If bExport Then
            ''' Export the component to a text file.
            cmpComponent.Export szExportPath & szFileName
        ''' remove it from the project if you want
        '''wkbSource.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove cmpComponent
        End If
    Next cmpComponent
    MsgBox "Export is ready"

End Sub
Function FolderWithVBAProjectFiles() As String
    Dim WshShell As Object
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim SpecialPath As String

    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    SpecialPath = "Z:\Planificacion-WFM\Planificacion Telefonica\Código"

    If Right(SpecialPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        SpecialPath = SpecialPath & "\"
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles") = False Then
        On Error Resume Next
        MkDir SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles"
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles") = True Then
        FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles"
    Else
        FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = "Error"
    End If

End Function
Function DeleteVBAModulesAndUserForms()
        Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

        For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
            If VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_Document Then
                'Thisworkbook or worksheet module
                'We do nothing
            ElseIf Not VBComp.Name Like "*Modulos*" Then 'ignore modules which name contain "Modulos"
                VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
            End If
        Next VBComp
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Damian, this is great. Do you know of a way to replace the modules on import? When i do, it imports it but then adds 1 at the end of it.

Comment: It first deletes the modules, if it's too fast there might be the 1 at the end (what I do is run again the macro)

Comment: Sorry, should have said. I have modified the code a bit. It doesn't delete all the modules. And now it only imports if the date modified is greater that a date in a cell. I then want it to only replace that module

Comment: You should delete always prior to the import, add the modifications to the delete function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but only if the "Trust access to the VBA project object module" has been granted. You will find this setting under Excel Options>Trust Center>Macro Settings.

As this is something that is set on each individual installation of excel, you can only do it if you know for certain this setting is activated. Otherwise any code you write will fail.

Comment: Yes, all installations can have that setting

Comment: You mean to say that you are certain that it is set to "ok" on all the workstations where your code will run? i.e. corporate environment that you know...

Comment: Yes, it can be set to ok. It isn't at the moment and i would have to check but they all can be.