# Delete a module with the same name as the one being imported

Tags: excel, vba, import, module

I am trying to set up an import module and I need it to delete modules before import if it meets a condition. There are 4 modules that it needs to check.

The code checks the files date modified against a range and then if the date is greater, it imports. The code when ran throws an error.

```vb
For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(szImportPath).Files
    If (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "bas") Or _
       (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "cls") Or _
       (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "frm") And _
        objFile.DateLastModified > Range("ImportDate") Then

        'Delete all modules/Userforms from the ActiveWorkbook
        'Call DeleteVBAModulesF    
        szFileName = objFile.Name

        Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(szFileName)
        VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp

        Range("MacroName") = objFile.Name
        Range("ImportDate") = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " " & Format(Time, "hh.nn.ss")
        '^ Keep time as without, it will import the same module throughout the day when opened.

        cmpComponents.Import objFile.path
    End If

Next objFile
```

I am hoping that it deletes the current module and then imports.

Comment: Hello Robert, see if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56630212/7558682) suits your needs.

Comment: @Damian Hi, i have worked it out and the code is below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Had to take the extension name of the end and it now works. Here is the [code](http://mariaevert.dk/vba/?p=162).

```
            Dim FileName

            FileName = Left(objFile.Name, (InStrRev(objFile.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

            Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
            Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

            Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
            Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(FileName)
            VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
```