# How make changes to multiple copy of a VB code in different places at the same time

Tags: excel, vba

Our company's QC personnel makes constant changes to our product description excel files and with every change they have to print the file and get it signed by 6 people. To go around this and save some paper we decided that a VB code should do the trick.
Now with every change, an email is sent to these individuals with the location of the file. To sign they need to open it up and click on the sign button. After their click, their username, and their PC's IP address gets checked and if it matches, the file gets stamped with their username, IP and time of the day.
Now, considering our company has a high turn over of staff, I have been asked to come up with a way to somehow, make changes to one file to be implemented to all the files that are running this VB code.
for example: changing the username of one of the stuff to the new member, I or their next IT person has to implement that change to every file that this VB code is running.
Now, I have been trying for a few days to come up with a solution and failing miserably at it. Any help would greatly be appreciated.
Below is a part of my code. The code itself works as intended.

```
If MsgBox("Are you authorised to sign this dacument?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

Temp = Environ("UserName")
change = LCase(Temp)

    If change = User1 Then
        MsgBox Join(Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").exec("cmd /c ipconfig").StdOut.readall, vbCrLf), "IP"), vbLf), 64, "*** DIGITALLY SIGNED *** IP-snb"
        WkVal = "Master  File (Technical Dept.):"
        Set WkRg = Range("C1:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Set F = WkRg.Find(What:=WkVal, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If (Not F Is Nothing) Then F.Offset(0, 6).Value = Now
        If (Not F Is Nothing) Then F.Offset(0, 4).Value = Application.UserName
        If (Not F Is Nothing) Then F.Offset(0, 5).Value = Environ("UserName")
        If (Not F Is Nothing) Then F.Offset(0, 7).Value = Join(Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").exec("cmd /c ipconfig").StdOut.readall, vbCrLf), "IP"), vbLf)

        Exit Sub

    End If
```

Comment: So what exactly is not working?  Getting an exception or unexpected results? or are you asking us to re-write your code?

Comment: Hi Hursey, the code itself works as intended but I have no idea if this function in question is even possible to implement in VB or if it is, where to start. Thanks

Comment: So if it is working as intended, what exact aspect of the implementation do you need assisting with?

Comment: This code will be implemented in many excel files. Any changes made to them needs to be approved by 6 different people. We have a high turn over of staff and if one of these people leaves then we have to go to these excel files and replace their name one by one to the new staff's name. We are trying to avoid that by writing a VB code that if you change any part of the code in one of these files all the other files that have the same code change too.

Comment: So repeating the question really doesn't help much. The code you've posted above.  How do you run that?  Do you have a vb console application that you expect to go through all these excel files?

Comment: it runs as a macro on an excel file, that's part of code though. I have written the code using Visual Basic for application(opening it up using ALT+F11 in a blank excel file). I don't have a VB console application, I am very new to the whole coding using VB as this is my first code ever written in VB. Hope this has answered the question, if not please let me know.

Comment: Your goal is tu automate the distribuition of new code to all excel files @VaniaMa? If so, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56630212/7558682), a previous answer with the same problem.

Comment: You should rethink your strategy.  User information like approvers/submitters/departments/authorized users/etc should not be hard coded into your programs and you are asking for trouble if you enable programmatic access to the VBA object model.  Instead, consider maintaining a list of current employees in a secure workbook so you only have 1 source to change.  Push updates to the user files via code in that secure workbook.  You can save user data in a `Very Hidden` worksheet or in a separate file.

Comment: @Damian, It is. I will look into it and try to understand it to see if it can be implemented. Thank you very much for taking the time to reply and provide a possible solution.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious, so make any changes that we want to that spreadsheet and distribute the changes from there to all of our other Excel files? Thanks for taking the time to answer by the way.

Comment: Yes, that is the gist of it.  There's no reason to alter any program code for a staffing change, your program should be designed so that an unskilled worker can maintain the file.